# How to use UIRotationGestureRecognizer for delayed rotation?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uigesturerecognizer

I would like to "detect" rotation - not to track it. I need to handle gesture rotation clockwise or counterclockwise by `M_PI/8` and then should rotate my image by `M_PI_2` or `-M_PI_2`.

Is it possible using `UIRotationGestureRecognizer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works as I need:

```
- (IBAction)rorationDid:(UIRotationGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    static CGFloat angle = 0;
    if (recognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan)
        angle = recognizer.rotation;
    if (recognizer.state != UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded)
        return;

    float rotation = 0;
    if (angle - recognizer.rotation > M_PI/8)
        rotation = -M_PI_2;
    if (angle - recognizer.rotation < -M_PI/8)
        rotation = M_PI_2;

    if (rotation != 0.0)
    {
        // Let's do rotation
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

This code: `static CGFloat angle = 0;` should really be a `@property` not `static`.